# gdb: get backtrace in multithread mode

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

My function **f** throws an exception, and my program doesn't handle it.  In gdb, I can get the backtrace as following

```
#0  0x00007ffff722ec59 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7230368 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7b35f85 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7b33ee6 in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7b33f13 in std::terminate() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7b3413f in __cxa_throw () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00000000004006e6 in g () at x.cc:2
#7  0x00000000004006ef in f () at x.cc:6
#8  0x00000000004006fa in main () at x.cc:10
```

but if I change it to multithread,

```
std::thread t(f);
t.join();
```

Here is the backtrace.

```
#0  0x00007ffff7011c59 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7013368 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7b35f85 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7b33ee6 in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7b33f13 in std::terminate() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7b8a345 in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff73a2f33 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff70d0ead in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Here is the test code:

```
void g() {
    throw 1;
}

void f() {
    g();
}

int main() {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

My tools version are:

GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.6.50.20130731-16.fc20
gcc version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7) (GCC)

I compiled it with:

```
g++ x.cc -o x -ggdb -O0 -pthred -std=c++11
```

My question is How can I get the full backtrace for case 2?

Comment: OP has stated in his question that he has already read the duplicate question and that is different from his hereby.

Comment: @Barry,  Could you remove the "dumplicate" flag?

Comment: The question is about getting a backtrace for multuple threads and you have that. If you want to ask about why your functions are getting optimized out, that's a different question.

Comment: OK. @barry, I have changed the title.  can you remove the duplicated flag?

Comment: Dude. Just ask a new question.

Comment: @Barry, could you tell me when to "ask a new question" or "edit this question"  in this case?  I don't think it is deserved to ask a new question while a extreme similar question is here already.  Per the stackoverflow's suggestion,  either "edit this question" or "ask a new question" is a right way to fix this issue.  Thanks